# How to disable Link Preview Chips in all Google Sheets/Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I am using Google Sheets and Docs a lot at work (like most people I assume) and the link previews severely hinder my ability to work quickly. I have tried to google around to see how to remove this, I understand there are chrome extensions that can employ css to hide them to a certain degree but not fully. I am wondering if there is a way to remove them completely from all docs - not just from one at a time. Thanks!

Comment: We'd need to know more. Do you or anyone else need to access these links ever again, or just to *see* them? Are they all grouped together in one range, or are they scattered throughout sheets haphazardly? Does your individual work task directly involve interacting with those links? The more you can tell us, the more there may be by way of suggestions particular to your situation.

Comment: @ErikTyler
Thanks - and maybe this image will help clarify: https://ibb.co/26RS25t
When you paste a link into text within Google Docs/Sheets, and then you hover over that link, you see a Link Preview.

My Sheets/Docs are filled with tons of links - so traversing the document I am constantly seeing these previews pop up on hover that are mini context switches every time, and I have to un-hover to stop seeing them - which breaks my work flow. Let me know if that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: In your goal, for example, when a value of "sample" in a cell as the smart chip, what result do you want to obtain? And, when the smart chips can be removed, do you want to restore them in the future?

Comment: @Tanaike
I think I mis-named the feature I am referring to and am trying to disable. I think it's just a link preview:
https://ibb.co/26RS25t

Do you know how to remove that? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your goal, you want to remove the hyperlink from all cells. In this case, that is not the smart chips. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike
Your understanding is correct. Thank you.
Let me know if you know how to remove the link preview :)

Comment: There's a difference between "removing the link preview" and "removing the hyperlink." Be sure you're talking apples and apples. If you remove hyperlinks, none of the links will *work*. As to my specific questions and your response, I understood what you were referring to from the start. However, you didn't answer any of the questions I posted (except "sort of" saying that your sheets/docs are "filled with tones of links"; but even that doesn't tell me if they are systematically placed or randomly strewn around. Look over my questions in the first comment again and consider replying to each.

Comment: @ErikTyler
Do you or anyone else need to access these links ever again, or just to see them? 
Yes.

Are they all grouped together in one range, or are they scattered throughout sheets haphazardly? 
Scattered.

Does your individual work task directly involve interacting with those links? 
I'm not sure what you mean by individual work task - I work with the docs and sheets throughout my work flow all the time in any and every context and there is no distinction between using the docs in one context vs. another for all intents and purposes.

Comment: Dave, if you yourself did not need to click links and visit URLs during the course of your own work, and if those links were grouped in certain columns or rows, I might have suggested that you merely hide those columns/rows during your work periods and unhide them at the end. If they are scattered haphazardly, that isn't an option. However, I may have a workaround. Do all of your links contain "http" or "https" at the front? Are they direct URLs or "pretty links" (e.g., using the `HYPERLINK` function)?

Comment: @ErikTyler
My links do contain https. A workaround would be great :) As long as the preview tile doesn't appear on hover and block a number of other cells. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I put in a little work to try a few things on your behalf. You can use the following steps. Each two-step process takes less than 10 seconds.

**When you are ready to begin work in a particular sheet:**

1.) Hit Ctrl-A to select the entire sheet range.

2.) With the entire sheet range selected, right click anywhere and hover over "View more cell actions" at the bottom of the menu that appears. Then choose "Remove links." All links in that sheet will now be deactivated.

**When you are done in that particular sheet:**

1.) Click Ctrl-H to bring up the Find/Replace dialog. (For this process, *do not* select the entire sheet first.)

2.) In the "Find" field enter `http`. In the "Replace with" field *also* enter `http`. For "Search" area, select "This sheet." Finally, hit the "Replace all" button. This should *reactivate all links* in that sheet.

---

Again, each of these two-step processes can be accomplished in just a few seconds.

Because this is an important work document, I would recommend that you practice this once or twice in a *copy* of some real sheet that has links in it (i.e., duplicate a real sheet within the spreadsheet, practice there, and when you're satisfied with your practice results, delete that duplicate sheet).

I also recommend before you do the first two-step process for any sheet, that you get in the habit of creating a new Named Range (**File > Version history > Name current version**), so that you can revert if needed. This is good practice for *anyone* who will be making significant changes to *any* sheet; and at the very least, it will provide peace of mind and confidence as you apply the workaround steps I've offered.

Comment: I really appreciate you making the extra effort, but (and I guess I should have specified this) I would like to kind of "switch off" the link previews for all docs without having to do it for each document respectively each time, which from what I am understanding from your reply that is what your solution suggests. 

Thanks anyway - I sincerely hope Google realizes how cumbersome this is and adds functionality to remove it.

Comment: I would recommend that you edit your original post to specify this, so that other volunteer contributors here don't wind up investing time trying to offer solutions that don't match your actual goal as now stated in your above comment.